# Properly writing that a set of variables take values from a certain set?

Tags: notation

I have a pretty dumb question. I know that if I have a pair $(a,b)$ that can take values in $\mathbb{R}$, I should write $(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2$.
But what about if I have a set? I want $\{a,b,c\}$ to all take values in $[1,3] = \{1,2,3\}$. Do I write $\{a,b,c\} \in [1,3]^3$?

Somehow it seems odd to me.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the example you mentioned, if you have an (*unordered*) *set*, e.g. $\{a,b,c\}$, then it is customary to write $$
\{a,b,c\} \subset [1,3].
$$
The notation $\subset$ means "is a subset of" as in
$$
\mbox{ a smaller set } \subset \mbox{ some larger set} 
$$
On the other hand, if you have an *ordered pair* or *ordered triple* (and so on), then it is customary to write the pair elements $(a,b)$ in parentheses and use the $\in$ and $\times$ symbols, as in
$$
(a,b) \in {\mathbb R}\times{\mathbb R}.
$$

Comment: That is what I have seen elsewhere, but it's .. dodgy, isn't it? It means that $\{a,b,c\}$ is a subset of $\{1,2,3\}$. I guess, $\{3,1,2\}$ is also a subset, so it induces all the possible values of a,b, and c. I get it, but it just seems odd. But thanks, that is what I had seen, and you confirmed it. (also, could be $\subseteq$).

Answer (score 1):

Yes that's right. People will also write $(a,b) \in A \times A$ or $(a,b,c) \in A \times A\times A$. You can also write something like "consider the pair $(a,b)$ where $a, b \in A$" (the last bit is read as "where $a$ and $b$ are in $A$).